# Integrate Source Safe WIth Visual Basic 6

Tags: visual-studio

I'm using Visual Basic 6.0 (SP6) and want to integrate Source Safe 2005 into the IDE, how can I set this up?

Thanks

Lennie De Villiers

Answer (score 0):

Several years since I last did this. 
But I think you need to run the Source Safe setup on your developer machine.

Regards, 
GAT

Answer (score 0):

Have you already installed visual studio and source safe? If so, read the following thread that explains how to select source safe as the source control plugin for your environment:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssourcecontrol/thread/c4511175-f4cd-4948-9d3e-7e041aa28160/

You should be seeing the SourceSafe on the File -> Open dialog once it is properly configured.

Comment: Hi, In Visual Basic 6 in Visual Studio 6 not Visual Studio 2005 etc. The pre-.Net days!